# what is the easiest way to find if a specific value exists in a table with multiple rows on a website using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, automation, nested-for-loop

I am trying to make my script perform a specific action based on the existence of a value in a table row on a website. E.g if x is in row 1 of table 'lab', create investigation, else move to next row and check if x is in that row. Sorry the website I am trying this on is not accessible by those who do not have an account but please see a simpler version of my code to help figure this out. As of now, I am stuck on the second for loop, the code below goes through each row and prints it out but just hangs. Might just be a break I am needing but I have tried it all (break, continue, pass).

```
#for each patient id in list, find the section in the patients web-table by looking through each row where the covid name and result is stored


#search for results table within a table in a web page for eicrs
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="xmlBlock"]/ul[1]/li/table[1]/tbody')
for idx, elem in enumerate(elems, 1):
    for rownum, lab in enumerate(elem.text.split('\n'), 1):
        
        #get lab test from first column for each row        
        lab_test = text_xpath(f'//*[@id="xmlBlock"]/ul[1]/li[{idx}]/table[1]/tbody/tr[{rownum}]/td[1]')
        
        #get result from second column for each row
        lab_result= text_xpath(f'//*[@id="xmlBlock"]/ul[1]/li[{idx}]/table[1]/tbody/tr[{rownum}]/td[2]') 
        
        #if lab test is in list of rna tests and positive lab regex, create CONFIRMED investigation
        if re.search(covid_test_names, lab_test.lower()) and re.search(pos_regex, lab_result.lower()): 
                        
            print('Log update: created confirmed investigation')              
        
        #else if lab test is in list of antigen tests and positive lab regex, create PROBABLE investigation
        elif re.search(ant_regex, lab_test.lower()) and re.search(antigen_pos_regex, lab_result.lower()):
            print('Log update: created probable investigation')          
        else:
            print('Log doc: No lab test matches regex', lab_test, lab_result)
            
            continue #continue loop through rows
        continue #not sure if needed
    break #break out of topmost for loop and move to next line of code once value has been found to match condition.
print('done with that')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need, you should remove both `continue` from your code and the `break` at the bottom as well and add a `break` inside the `if` and `else` blocks so if you found the condition you are looking for and performed the action you need - now break the for loop.
Like this:

```py
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="xmlBlock"]/ul[1]/li/table[1]/tbody')
for idx, elem in enumerate(elems, 1):
    for rownum, lab in enumerate(elem.text.split('\n'), 1):
        
        #get lab test from first column for each row        
        lab_test = text_xpath(f'//*[@id="xmlBlock"]/ul[1]/li[{idx}]/table[1]/tbody/tr[{rownum}]/td[1]')
        
        #get result from second column for each row
        lab_result= text_xpath(f'//*[@id="xmlBlock"]/ul[1]/li[{idx}]/table[1]/tbody/tr[{rownum}]/td[2]') 
        
        #if lab test is in list of rna tests and positive lab regex, create CONFIRMED investigation
        if re.search(covid_test_names, lab_test.lower()) and re.search(pos_regex, lab_result.lower()): 
                        
            print('Log update: created confirmed investigation')              
            break
        
        #else if lab test is in list of antigen tests and positive lab regex, create PROBABLE investigation
        elif re.search(ant_regex, lab_test.lower()) and re.search(antigen_pos_regex, lab_result.lower()):
            print('Log update: created probable investigation')          
            break
        else:
            print('Log doc: No lab test matches regex', lab_test, lab_result)
                        
has been found to match condition.
print('done with that')
```

But maybe I do not understand your logic and the question

Comment: Great suggestion @Prophet. Cant believe that's just what i needed.

Comment: It's OKay, just some experience / hands on :)

Comment: Hey @prophet I have a selenium question for you. Please could you navigate to my page or this link to read my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70085338/how-do-i-control-the-new-mozilla-firefox-browser-update-91-3-0esr-with-selenium

Comment: Hi, I don't know the answer to that question. Also, it was already closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Alright, thanks for checking! I will reframe the question and repost.